# How to vertical align (center) the content of UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I want to center the content of my `UITableView` that contains `headerView` and `footerView` created at storyboard, and `UITableViewCell`s. How can I achieve this?

Here is what I'm trying to implement to solve my problem but this does not work.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    CGFloat height = self.tableView.frameHeight - self.navigationController.navigationBar.frameHeight - [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height - (self.rowCount * self.rowHeight);
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView.frameHeight = height / 2.0;
}
```

So I subtracted the height of the navigationBar & statusBar and cells' height to the tableView's height to get the height of the empty area.
Now that I get the height if the empty area, I divided it to 2 for the footer and header's view.

Comment: set frame of table view dynamically

Comment: paste some code what did u tried yet?

Comment: @LalitKumar, I updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by center ?

Comment: can you add image what did you want?

Comment: @LalitKumar, this is what I want: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5EXlMeZdF31R0JpcXF1RjUwZnc/view?usp=sharing
this is the current: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5EXlMeZdF31UGhldFhibEZBVXc/view?usp=sharing

Sorry, I don't have enough reputations to upload photo.

Comment: @LalitKumar, Yes, it is and I'm using autolayout.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the **viewWillAppear** and in the **didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation** functions :

```
CGFloat headerHeight = (self.view.frame.size.height - (ROW_HEIGHT * [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]))) / 2;

self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(headerHeight, 0, -headerHeight, 0);
```

This will solve your problem.

**EDIT**

Call the **updateTableViewContentInset** function in the **viewWillLayoutSubviews** and after each **reloadData** :

**Ojective-C**

```
- (void)updateTableViewContentInset {
    CGFloat viewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat tableViewContentHeight = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
    CGFloat marginHeight = (viewHeight - tableViewContentHeight) / 2.0;

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(marginHeight, 0, -marginHeight, 0);
}
```

**Swift 4**

```
func updateTableViewContentInset() {
    let viewHeight: CGFloat = view.frame.size.height
    let tableViewContentHeight: CGFloat = tableView.contentSize.height
    let marginHeight: CGFloat = (viewHeight - tableViewContentHeight) / 2.0

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: marginHeight, left: 0, bottom:  -marginHeight, right: 0)
}
```

Comment: Your solutions is very elegant and clean, just fails n the case you have a dynamic number of cells. If  your table has too many cells it won't be displayed correctly. So the following will fix this problem: `headerHeight = MAX(0, headerHeight);`

Comment: Why not to use `self.tableView.rowHeight` instead of `ROW_HEIGHT`?

Comment: Test in ios 12, swift 4.2
I must add:
        `tv.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension` &
        `tv.estimatedRowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension`

Comment: what if there is adjusted content inset ?

Answer (score 16):

Override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and compare the tableView's `frame` with its `contentSize` to set its `contentInset`. In Swift 4 :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    let tableViewHeight = self.tableView.frame.height
    let contentHeight = self.tableView.contentSize.height

    let centeringInset = (tableViewHeight - contentHeight) / 2.0
    let topInset = max(centeringInset, 0.0)

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)
}
```

This works well with self-sizing table view cells

Comment: To make it true Swift 4, change the last line to:
`self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)`

Comment: @RaulHuerta : Indeed 'UIEdgeInsetsMake' has been replaced by 'UIEdgeInsets.init(top:left:bottom:right:), I updated my answer

Comment: In `viewDidLayoutSubviews ` the `self.tableView.contentSize.height` is being calculated form the `estimatedRowHeight` not the actual resized cells. moving this to `viewDidAppear` will do the trick. But not sure if that is a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `contentSize` property of `UITableView`, that how you don't have to take the cell `height` or `count` into account.

```
- (void) updateTableInsetsForHeight: (CGFloat) height
{
    CGFloat tableViewInset = MAX((height - self.tableView.contentSize.height) / 2.0, 0.f);
    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(tableViewInset, 0, -tableViewInset, 0);
}
```

Update the `contentInsets` after reloading `tableView`-data, and when the containing view of the `tableView` becomes visible (`viewWillAppear:`) and when it changes size (`viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`).

```
- (void) viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [self updateTableInsetsForHeight: size.height];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 based on Pipiks answer

```
let headerHeight: CGFloat = (view.frame.size.height - CGFloat(Int(tableView.rowHeight) * tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0))) / 2
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(headerHeight, 0, -headerHeight, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `UIView` at the top (UIView should be parent of your TableView) of your `TableView` from storyboard. After that set its constraints to fill the view. Now, set the size of your TableView and set its constraints to center both vertically and horizontally your top 
`UIView`. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what causing my computation wrong. The value of self.tableView.bounds.size.height is different from the actual height in viewWillAppear. I used self.view.bounds.size.height instead.

Answer (score 0):

for **SWIFT 3 :**

```
var headerHeight: CGFloat = (tableView.frame.size.height - CGFloat(Int(tableView.rowHeight) * tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0))) / 2
if headerHeight > 0 {
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(headerHeight, 0, 0/*-headerHeight*/, 0)
} else {
    headerHeight = 0
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(headerHeight, 0, 0/*-headerHeight*/, 0)
}
```

**RESULT :**

[image][image]
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use KVO to watch for when the contentSize of the tableView changes. I found this the best way when using automatic row height.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", context: nil)
}

deinit {
    tableView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize")
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if (keyPath == "contentSize") {
        if (tableView.contentSize.height < tableView.frame.height) {
            let inset = (tableView.frame.height - tableView.contentSize.height) / 2
            tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: inset, left: 0, bottom: inset, right: 0)
        } else {
            tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set frame of your UITableView like this

```
CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height;
CGFloat tableHeight = 200.0; //your table height
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,(height-tableHeight)/2,width,tableHeight);
```

or try this

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to change the frame of my tableView since I'm using autolayout.